# Change color of mat-select based on mat-option

Tags: angular, angular-material, frontend, mat-form-field, mat-select

So I have a dropdown:

```html
<div class="drop-down" >    
    <mat-select>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let role of roles | keyvalue" [value]="role">
            {{role['value']}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>      
</div>
```

Roles is an enum:

```js
export enum Role {
    a='Software Tester (Manual)',
    b='Software Tester (Automation)',
    c='Software Tester',
    d='System Tester'
}
```

I would like to change the color of `mat-select` based on the option chosen from the dropdown menu. I think using `ngClass` would be a solution, but I don't really know how to use it  in this case based on the `enum` value selected.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hewot8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-overview-example.ts) of what you would like to achieve.

I used the `ngClass` directive and `selectionChange` event on `mat-select` to detect the option selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ng-style

```
ng-style="IfCondition1 ? checkAnotherCondition && {'color':'red'} : {'color': 'green','font-weight':'bolder'}"
```